# "I'm Feeling Lucky"-style behavior in Windows 8.1 search?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search, feeling-lucky

Is it possible to make Windows 8.1 automatically select the most relevant search result, so that I could just press `Enter` to execute it? Right now, I have to press down-arrow each time to select it, and *then* press `Enter`.

I occasionally forget to press the down-arrow, and Windows opens that *very useful* Search Results window for me. It makes me sad since I'm absolutelly happy with the top search result nearly all the time.

P.S.: I'm taking about the Search in Start menu (the menu which opens when I press `winkey`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it to be context dependent.

If the input text is part of existing program, the first result is pre-selected and pressing enter results in running the program. This is similar to the "I am feeling lucky" style behavior.

If the input text is not matching any existing program, or has any parameter at the end, there is no selection and pressing enter results in getting to search result page.

Comment: Yep, looks like it's the way it works. I got used to it, kind of.